# Inline a function call, where an expression was expected

Tags: powershell

In powershell, I'm trying to do this:

```
$binRoot =  ($path, Get-BinPath)[$path -eq $null]
```

Here, `Get-BinPath` is a function defined earlier.  I get an error on this line which says:

```
At C:\repos\hub\test.ps1:12 char:20
+ $binRoot =  ($path, Get-BinPath)[$path -eq $null]
+                    ~
Missing expression after ','.
At C:\repos\hub\test.ps1:12 char:21
+ $binRoot =  ($path, Get-BinPath)[$path -eq $null]
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Get-BinPath' in expression or statement.
```

I can fix this by splitting the work into two statements, and introducing a temporary variable - but it would be nice to do it in one line.  And even if that is bad etiquette, I'm still just curious of how this can be done.

Comment: As an aside: I recommend forming a habit of putting a literal to compare against on the _LHS_ - `$null -eq $path`, in this case - to avoid surprises if the variable being compared happens to be a collection (array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `Get-BinPath` in brackets; this causes the function to be evaluated as an expression, i.e. as if it were being called separately:

```
$binRoot =  ($path, (Get-BinPath))[$path -eq $null]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$binRoot = if ($path -ne $null) {$path} else {Get-BinPath}
```

is few chars longer. However less cryptic and easier to read (understand, maintain, etc..)